# Giving a closed form combinatorial solution to finding the larger of two balls drawn from an urn

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I understand how to solve the following problem by listing out the sample space; however, I would like to know how to derive a combinatorial solution to the problem (that is, I would like to give a closed form solution to n(X=0), n(X=1), etc.)

An urn contains 4 balls numbered 0 to 3. If two balls are drawn with replacement, define the random variable X to be the larger of the two balls drawn. Find P(X=0), P(X=1), P(X=2), and P(X=3).

Comment: $$P(X=k)=\frac{2k+1}{4^2}$$

Comment: That's awesome- thank you! Unfortunately, I looks as if I worded my question incorrectly. What I would really to know is how to count n(X=0), n(X=1), etc.

Comment: For n(X=2), I tried the following: first, of the two spots, I chose the location of the 2; then, for the remaining spot, I chose 1 number of the 3 numbers less than or equal to 2. Hence, I obtained 2! * (3 choose 1), which is incorrect

Comment: same thing as bof's formula, just don't divide by the size of the sample space ... $$n(X=k) = 2k+1$$

Comment: @SimoneC I gave the formula for $P(X=k)$ because I guessed that $P$ stood for probability. You didn't define what you meant by $n(X=k)$ and I didn't feel like guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 0**: $X=0$

The only way that the largest ball drawn is $0$ is if we pick $0$ both times, so

$$n(X=0) = \boxed{1}$$

**Case 1**: $X=1$

We can either have both draws be $1$, or one draw be $0$ and the other $1$. There are two ways to draw $0$ and $1$, one for each order, so we get

$$n(X=1) = 1+2 = \boxed{3}$$

**Case 2**: $X=2$

Once again, we can have both draws be $2$, or one draw be $2$ and the other be $0$ or $1$. This time there are $4$ ways to have only one of the draws be $2$, which gives

$$n(X=2) = 1+2+2 = \boxed{5}$$

**Case 3**: $X=3$

Both draws could be $3$, or one draw could be $3$ and the other be $0$, $1$, or $2$. This time there are $6$ ways to have only one of the draws be $3$, so we get

$$n(X=3) = 1+2+2+2 = \boxed{7}$$

---

As a check, notice that $n(X=0)+n(X=1)+n(X=2)+n(X=3) = 16$, which is the size of the sample space.

You can also compactly write this (bof wrote something similar in the comments):

$$n(X=k) = 2k+1$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof without words:

[image]

Comment: That's beautiful! +1

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$|\{(a,b):(a=k\quad\text{and} \quad b \leq a) \quad \text{or} \quad(b=k\quad\text{and} \quad a \leq b) \}|=2(k+1)-1=2k+1$$
for 
$
0\leq k\leq 3.
$